# Selenium - How to get attribute values with same tag names and no class/id?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, attributes, webdriver

got a quick question, since I'm kind of baffled.
I'm looking to get this:

```
<meta property="article:tag" content="amd">
<meta property="article:tag" content="game">
<meta property="article:tag" content="what">
```

into either a list or simple "nextValueOf".

Currently I have this such code:

```
String urlTag = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//meta[@property='article:tag']")).getAttribute("content");
```

But when I either change it to "getAttributes" it won't work or when I loop it it constantly spits only the 1st one.
What am I missing here?

Thanks a bunch in advance. :)

P.S. Due to how my code works I can get them in 1 by 1 and not as a list, so that's no such a requirement - I just need to grab them all as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `findElement()` you can use the `findElements()` method to create a *List* and iterate through the *List* to print the values of the attribute **content** as follows :

```
List <WebElement> urlTag = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//meta[@property='article:tag']"));
for(WebElement tag:urlTag)
    System.out.println(tag.getAttribute("content"));
```

Comment: That's what's I've been looking for, thanks!

Any advice on how to make it into a single String for .sendKeys? It seems that String.join doesn't really work here.

Comment: @Zubkover Can I request you to raise a new ticket for your new requirement please? Stackoverflow volunteers will be happy to help you out.